# Multiply two lists of raster from two subfolder

Tags: python, arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.1, list

I have two subfolders, which contains rasters for each country but which express different variables.  I am trying to figure out a way to Loop a multiplication of each raster into a folder with its pair of the other subfolder. Looks like:.

```
AFG_13      AFG_25.tif_int     for Afghanistan
AGO_13      AGO_25.tif_int     for Angola
etc...
```

where the first column rapresents the total population and the second is like a mask (infact I need only the pixel with values 25 converted in the pixel value 1)

In other words I need to multiply `AFG_13*con(AFG_25.tif_int==25,1)` in Python..I tried already to solve the problem in different ways, but still nothing...some advice?

Answer (score 1):

The following requires a Spatial Analyst license.

The ArcPy [Raster Object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000) provides a pretty intuitive interface to working with rasters. Once a Raster Object is created, you're allowed to perform math operations on it in a very similar manner to operations on python built-in objects. Properties and methods onboard the Raster Object should also be useful for identifying your rasters in terms of your *"AFG*" etc. naming convention.

I'd start by making a list of rasters in each of my subfolders, and then iterate through these lists and create raster objects for all rasters. Then, for only those rasters which contain, for example, *"AFG*" in the name, I would isolate them and perform my math operations. Finally, I'd save the result raster to a permanent file on-disk.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
import os

country_code = 'AFG_'
variable_code_one = '13'
variable_code_two = '25'
folder_one = 'C:/rasters/folder_one'
folder_two = 'C:/rasters/folder_two'
output_folder = 'C:/rasters/output'
folders_list = [folder_one, folder_two]
raster_objects_list = []

# filter available rasters by country code and create raster objects
for folder in folders_list:
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    for raster in arcpy.ListRasters('*' + country_code, 'TIF'):
        raster.split('.')[0] = arcpy.Raster(raster)
        raster_objects_list.append(raster.split('.')[0])

# perform the math operations on the raster objects (this is probably not the best way)
# This assumes there is only 1 "_13" variable raster and only 1 "_25" variable raster available in the set
for raster in raster_objects_list:
    if variable_code_one in raster.name:
        variable_one_raster = raster

for raster in raster_objects_list:
    if variable_code_two in raster.name:
        variable_two_raster = raster

output_raster = (variable_one_raster * variable_two_raster) # or any other math operation
output_raster.save(output_folder + os.sep + country_code + '_results')
```

Best Luck with this.